# Issues with array_search

Tags: php

When I run the following, I get `'B.C.'`, but I'm trying to get `'BC'`.

I set `array_search` to do a strict comparison, why isn't it returning `"BC"`?

If I pass `"Alberta"`, I get `"AB"`, which is correct.

```
<?
function cleanProvince($province)
{
    $values = array(
        'AB' => 'Alberta',
        'BC' => 'B.C.',
        'BC' => 'British Columbia',
        'ON' => 'Ontario',
        'ON' => 'Onatrio',
        'ON' => 'Ont',
        'NS' => 'Nova Scotia',
        'QC' => 'Quebec'
    );
    if ($key = array_search(@$province, $values, true)) {
        return $key;
    } else {
        return $province;
    }
}
echo (cleanProvince("B.C."));
?>
```

Comment: jrubins: He gets 'B.C.' as specified in the post.

Comment: You probably would do better to build your array with the long names as keys, and the abbreviations as values. Then search the keys, which will not be duplicated.

Comment: The error suppression operator isn't your friend. Use `isset()`, etc. (*also, in this case it'll never suppress anything anyway*)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You cannot have multiple keys in one array.  When you do that, the 2nd one overrides the first.

```
$values = array(
    'AB'=>'Alberta',
    'BC'=>'B.C.',
    'BC'=>'British Columbia', # Overrides 'B.C.'
    'ON'=>'Ontario',
    'ON'=>'Onatrio', # Overrides 'Ontario'
    'ON'=>'Ont', # Overrides 'Onatrio'
    'NS'=>'Nova Scotia',
    'QC'=>'Quebec',
);
```

You're passing `"B.C."` to `cleanProvince`.  That's not in `$values`, so `array_search` returns `false`, thus `cleanProvince` returns `"B.C."`.

Comment: @Rocket If key is different and value is same for two elements, then array_search only returns first one is it ? How to get all elements from here ?

Comment: @Jusnit: Use [`array_keys`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php) instead.  `$keys = array_keys($values, $province, TRUE)`.

Answer (score 1):

As has been recommended, swapping your keys and values will produce the desired results, and avoid the call to `array_search()` which I can only assume has considerably higher overhead (*moot point in most cases, but if called iteratively...*).

```
function getProvince($name){
    $values = array(
        'Onatrio' => 'ON',
        'Ontaroi' => 'ON',
        'O.N.' => 'ON',
        // ...
    );
    return isset($values[$name]) 
        ? $values[$name] 
        : $name; // or null I suppose
}
```